# Аргумент шаблона по умолчанию не может быть указан в определении члена шаблона класса вне класса

Tags: c++

```
template<typename Tp, class C = std::vector<Tp>>
struct A {
    C s{};    
    void change(const C&);
};

template<typename Tp, class C = std::vector<Tp>> //Ошибка (активный) E0953
void A<Tp, C>::change(const C& seq) {/*...*/ }
```

Очевидно, что при определении члена класса, нет  смысла указывать аргумент шаблона по умолчанию. Но вопрос в том, почему компилятор это считает ошибкой? (Может плохо смотрел, но кажется не было похожего вопроса).

Answer (score 6):

http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#12

> A default template-argument shall not be specified in the
> template-parameter-lists of the definition of a member of a class
> template that appears outside of the member's class.

[Релевантный баг в gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53856)

Почему так сделано?

Например, в следующем примере

```
template <class T = int>
struct A {
    T foo();
};

int main() {
    auto a = A{};
}
```

мы можем использовать дефолтный аргумент и не определять/инстанцировать функцию `foo`, потому что она не используется. А если бы можно было указывать дефолтные аргументы вне класса

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    T foo();
};

template <class T = int>
T A<T>::foo() {
    return T{};
}

int main() {
    auto a = A{};
}
```

то, для того чтобы узнать дефолтный аргумент, необходимо было бы искать определение функции, которая нам не нужна.

Теоретически можно сохранить возможность повторного определения точно такого же аргумента, как у вас в примере

```
template <class T = int>
struct A {
    T foo();
};

template <class T = int>
T A<T>::foo() {
    return T{};
}

int main() {
    auto a = A{};
}
```

но это не имеет смысла, потому что нет плюсов (по крайней мере я не вижу, для чего это может использоваться), но есть минус – дополнительная нагрузка на компиляторы для проверки равенства аргументов.

Comment: Хорошо, но  цитировать, что  это не должно быть так и повторять, что это ошибка, не считаю ответом на мой вопрос, потому что  интересует почему это так, а не можно или нельзя. То, что нельзя, я уже сам сказал в вопросе.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan *"почему компилятор это считает ошибкой?"* – потому что так сказано в стандарте. Соответствующий стандарту компилятор обязан так делать. Почему такую возможность не добавить? – потому что в ней нет смысла, это шаблонный параметр класса, а не функции, так что если указывать дефолтный аргумент ещё раз – только точно такой же, а это бойлерплейт

Comment: представьте себе, что я только изучаю, и мне не понятна причина. Все таки программирование, это не служба в армии, чтобы не обсуждать  решение командира.  Раз сказано в стандарте, значит это так. Но мыслящий человек хочет понять причину. Да в стандарте об этом говорится. И то что говорится в стандарте,  имеет основание,  и компилятор не может не считать  это  ошибкой.  "Потому что так сказано в стандарте" _ это не объяснение и не ответ. Тут не важно что я понимаю или вы, а важно  читать ответ на вопрос. Этим ответом пользуюсь не только я...... .

Comment: @ARHovsepyan добавил обоснование этого правила

Comment: Это уже другое дело, ответ отмечен,  но я бы  предпочел услышать другой ответ.